# Read an excel file in fulfillment of DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Is it possible to upload an excel/json file for a bot and read through it by code written in the fulfillment after an intent is matched.
example, I have a dictionary in excel format, I want to take user input and for that word return the meaning. All the words are stored in an excel along with their meanings. Can this be done by writing js code in fulfillment to read excel (which might be stored somewhere)
or we need to go by creating a webhook for a DB as shown here https://medium.com/@pallavtrivedi03/how-to-make-a-webhook-for-dialogflow-fulfillment-d02835cc50bf  ?

Answer (score 2):

Your fulfillment webhook code can do (mostly) anything that you can do in code, as long as you do it quickly enough.

If you have a [library that can read the excel format](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=excel), then you should be able to use it in your fulfillment.

The article you reference just happens to do that with a database, but you can use anything as long as you have (or can write) a library.